# Specifying generic collection type param at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, casting, runtime

I have:

```
class Car {..}
class Other{
  List<T> GetAll(){..}
}
```

I want to do:

```
Type t = typeof(Car);
List<t> Cars = GetAll<t>();
```

How can I do this?

I want to return a generic collection from the database of a type that I discover at runtime using reflection.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Type generic = typeof(List<>);    
Type specific = generic.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));    
ConstructorInfo ci = specific.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);    
object o = ci.Invoke(new object[] { });
```

Comment: This isnt a big deal or anything, but you can replace your empty type array being passed into GetConstructor with Type.EmptyTypes. Just a little cleaner, that's all.

Answer (score 8):

You could use reflection for this:

```
Type t = typeof(Car);
System.Type genericType= generic.MakeGenericType(new System.Type[] { t});
Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, args);
```