# Creating a Generic List of a specified type

Tags: vb.net, list, generics

I want to create a generic list - but I want to specify the type at runtime - is there a way I can do this? using reflection perhaps?

Something like this...

```
Public Shared Sub create(ByVal t As Type) 

  Dim myList As New Generic.List(Of t)

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

James

Comment: Well in that case try System.Reflection.Emit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If callers know the type, you can make the method itself generic:

```
Public Shared Sub create(Of t)() 
    Dim myList As New Generic.List(Of t)
End Sub
```

If callers do not know the type, you'll have to resort to reflection - [see the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513952/c-specifying-generic-collection-type-param-at-runtime) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I have a function to do exactly that:

```
Public Shared Function CreateList(Of T)(ByVal ParamArray items() As T) As List(Of T)
    Return New List(Of T)(items)
End Function
```

For instance, I can create a list of integers by doing this:

```
dim L as list(of Integer) = CreateList(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Or create a list of, say, textboxes:

```
dim L as list(of TextBox) = CreateList(txtPhone1, txtPhone2, txtPhone3)
```

Or in general, any type.