# How should I call the generic function without knowing the type at compile time?

Tags: c#, generics

Lets say, If I have a situation like the following.

```
Type somethingType = b.GetType();
    // b is an instance of Bar();

Foo<somethingType>(); //Compilation error!!
    //I don't know what is the Type of "something" at compile time to call
    //like Foo<Bar>();


//Where:
public void Foo<T>()
{
    //impl
}
```

How should I call the generic function without knowing the type at compile time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# specifying generic collection type param at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513952/c-specifying-generic-collection-type-param-at-runtime)

Comment: any many other. please use search before asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to use reflection:

```
MethodInfo methodDefinition = GetType().GetMethod("Foo", new Type[] { });
MethodInfo method = methodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(somethingType);
method.Invoke();
```

When writing a generic method, it's good practice to provide a non-generic overload where possible. For instance, if the author of `Foo<T>()` had added a `Foo(Type type)` overload, you wouldn't need to use reflection here.

Comment: Just one correction: MethodInfo method = methodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(somethingType);

Comment: Thanks, corrected. This one must have slipped past my Stack Overflow Unit Test Suite.

Comment: ?
What if the function "Foo<T>()" is an extension method to the type. Would it be listed in MethodInfo[]? or GetMethod(..)?

Comment: No, it'll be a static method on whichever class defines the extension method