# How to cast a generic type at runtime in c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I need to create an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` when I only know `T` at runtime.

I have built up my collection like so:

```
new List<List<object>>()
```

where all the objects in the inner list are a `T`

However because of co/contravariance (can never remember which it is!) my `List` of `List`s isnt an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable`s.

What can I do about this?

I've tried using `Convert.ChangeType` but it moans that `List` isn't `IConvertible`

**Clue:** Read the question. Again. I said I only know `T` at runtime.

Comment: Its possible that this question has already been asked http://stackoverflow.com/q/513952/462285

Comment: Could you show us the code, where you attempted to do it? If you know `T` only at runtime, how do you convert to `IE<IE<T>>`?

Comment: @nEm not exactly but thanks, i could create the inner list of the right type, but then i can push `object`s into it and i still have the variance issue

Comment: ah ok... sorry then... now i understood what you mean

Comment: @nEm youre the first one that does then!

Comment: What you mean under "I know T only in runtime"?

Comment: well maybe then I have underestimated the question...

Comment: yes, actually. its a parser. converting csv data into a strongly typed collection

Comment: I don't understand that is a T is this a generic type parameter or a type object?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359%28v=vs.80%29.aspx is this what you are trying to say with the variance issue?

Comment: Why you need strongly typed object if you don't know a type on compile time? I don't understand you!

Comment: I put that as an answer... with a more updated link... did it help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK, based on Master Morality's answer, I've come up with this. Shockingly simple.

```
public static IEnumerable Cast(this IEnumerable self, Type innerType)
{
    var methodInfo = typeof (Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast");
    var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(innerType);
    return genericMethod.Invoke(null, new [] {self}) as IEnumerable;
}
```

Simple. Blogged about it here: [Casting an enumerable when the inner type is only known at runtime](https://web.archive.org/web/20160821061502/http://blog.muonlab.com/2011/10/07/casting-an-enumerable-when-the-inner-type-is-only-known-at-runtime/)

Comment: Just FYI the link you mentioned is broken.

Comment: Down vote for the broken link. The solution should come with an explanation fully encapsulated in the answer without the need to go to another resource. Linking within StackOverflow is okay but external links are precarious as in this case. The full explanation is now unavailable to us because of it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use it untyped as `IEnumerable<IEnumerable>`
2. Use reflection to call a function that takes a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` with the appropriate `T`
3. use a switch statement to cast to appropriate type
4. use `dynamic`

---

**Examples**

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> castList<T>(List<List<object>> list) {
    return list.Select(x => x.Cast<T>());
}
void DoSomething(Type myT, List<List<object>> list) {
    object untyped = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("castList")
        .MakeGenericMethod(myT)
        .Invoke(null, new[] { list });
    // untyped is an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<myT>> at runtime, 
    // but obviously you don't know that at compile time.

    // what can you do with untyped? 
    // 1: use it like an untyped container
    var option1 = (IEnumerable<IEnumerable>)untyped;
    foreach(var inner in option1)
        foreach(object item in inner)
            Console.WriteLine(object);
    // 2: pass it to a function that you reflect on using
    //    the above makeGenericMethod strategy
    typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("Process")
        .MakeGenericMethod(myT)
        .Invoke(null, new[] { untyped });
    // 3: Cast it conditionally
    switch(Type.GetTypeCode(myT)) {
        case TypeCode.Int32:
             Process((IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>)untyped);
             break;
        case TypeCode.Single:
             Process((IEnumerable<IEnumerable<float>>)untyped);
             break;
    }
    // 4: make it a dynamic
    dynamic dyn = untyped;
    Process(dyn);
}
static void Process<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ienumerable) {
    Console.WriteLine("Processing type: {0}", typeof(T).Name);
    foreach(var inner in ienumerable)
        foreach(T item in inner)
            DoSomething(item); // item is now type T
}
```

Comment: "when I only know T at runtime"

Comment: I believe the OP said T is not known at compile-time.

Comment: @AndrewBullock okay added code for reflection. It's probably what you're asking for.

Comment: again, "when I only know T at runtime". youve written `INT` into the code at compile time. I have `var myT = typeof(int)`. All I have to work with is `myT`

Comment: @AndrewBullock Because it's an example. the result of the method is an Invoke, which is statically typed as `object`. If you want to do something with that `object`, then you have to cast it.

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar issues with TinyIoC, and rather than "converting", the "cleanest" solution I've found is to make your method generic (so public IEnumerable'T DoStuff'T()), then call that using MakeGenericMethod using your runtime type. It stays "clean" because your actual method that constructs the list just operates as if it is a normal generic method, so it doesn't get cluttered with casting etc.

Without seeing your code it's hard to know if that fits the bill - here's the relevant bits to make the generic method from TinyIoc:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    private static SafeDictionary<GenericMethodCacheKey, MethodInfo> _genericMethodCache;

    static TypeExtensions()
    {
        _genericMethodCache = new SafeDictionary<GenericMethodCacheKey, MethodInfo>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a generic method from a type given the method name, binding flags, generic types and parameter types
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceType">Source type</param>
    /// <param name="bindingFlags">Binding flags</param>
    /// <param name="methodName">Name of the method</param>
    /// <param name="genericTypes">Generic types to use to make the method generic</param>
    /// <param name="parameterTypes">Method parameters</param>
    /// <returns>MethodInfo or null if no matches found</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException"/>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException"/>
    public static MethodInfo GetGenericMethod(this Type sourceType, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingFlags, string methodName, Type[] genericTypes, Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
        MethodInfo method;
        var cacheKey = new GenericMethodCacheKey(sourceType, methodName, genericTypes, parameterTypes);

        // Shouldn't need any additional locking
        // we don't care if we do the method info generation
        // more than once before it gets cached.
        if (!_genericMethodCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out method))
        {
            method = GetMethod(sourceType, bindingFlags, methodName, genericTypes, parameterTypes);
            _genericMethodCache[cacheKey] = method;
        }

        return method;
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetMethod(Type sourceType, BindingFlags bindingFlags, string methodName, Type[] genericTypes, Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
        var methods =
            sourceType.GetMethods(bindingFlags).Where(
                mi => string.Equals(methodName, mi.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)).Where(
                    mi => mi.ContainsGenericParameters).Where(mi => mi.GetGenericArguments().Length == genericTypes.Length).
                Where(mi => mi.GetParameters().Length == parameterTypes.Length).Select(
                    mi => mi.MakeGenericMethod(genericTypes)).Where(
                        mi => mi.GetParameters().Select(pi => pi.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(parameterTypes)).ToList();

        if (methods.Count > 1)
        {
            throw new AmbiguousMatchException();
        }

        return methods.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private sealed class GenericMethodCacheKey
    {
        private readonly Type _sourceType;

        private readonly string _methodName;

        private readonly Type[] _genericTypes;

        private readonly Type[] _parameterTypes;

        private readonly int _hashCode;

        public GenericMethodCacheKey(Type sourceType, string methodName, Type[] genericTypes, Type[] parameterTypes)
        {
            _sourceType = sourceType;
            _methodName = methodName;
            _genericTypes = genericTypes;
            _parameterTypes = parameterTypes;
            _hashCode = GenerateHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var cacheKey = obj as GenericMethodCacheKey;
            if (cacheKey == null)
                return false;

            if (_sourceType != cacheKey._sourceType)
                return false;

            if (!String.Equals(_methodName, cacheKey._methodName, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                return false;

            if (_genericTypes.Length != cacheKey._genericTypes.Length)
                return false;

            if (_parameterTypes.Length != cacheKey._parameterTypes.Length)
                return false;

            for (int i = 0; i < _genericTypes.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (_genericTypes[i] != cacheKey._genericTypes[i])
                    return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < _parameterTypes.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (_parameterTypes[i] != cacheKey._parameterTypes[i])
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _hashCode;
        }

        private int GenerateHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var result = _sourceType.GetHashCode();

                result = (result * 397) ^ _methodName.GetHashCode();

                for (int i = 0; i < _genericTypes.Length; ++i)
                {
                    result = (result * 397) ^ _genericTypes[i].GetHashCode();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < _parameterTypes.Length; ++i)
                {
                    result = (result * 397) ^ _parameterTypes[i].GetHashCode();
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called as follows:

```
private object GetIEnumerableRequest(Type type)
{
    var genericResolveAllMethod = this.GetType().GetGenericMethod(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, "ResolveAll", type.GetGenericArguments(), new[] { typeof(bool) });

    return genericResolveAllMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { false });
}
```

And ResolveAll is defined as:

```
public IEnumerable<ResolveType> ResolveAll<ResolveType>()
    where ResolveType : class
{
    return ResolveAll<ResolveType>(true);
}
```

Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: If you only know T at run time, you could do it by building an expression. and compiling it. like so:

```
var listOfLists = new List<List<object>>();

//... do list building...

//types
var runTimeType = typeof(MyRuntimeType);
var innerListType = typeof(List<>)
    .MakeGenericType(typeof(object));
var innerEnumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>)
    .MakeGenericType(runTimeType);
var outerListType = typeof(List<>)
    .MakeGenericType(innerListType);

//methods
var castm = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast")
    .MakeGenericMethod(runTimeType);
var selectm = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Select").First()
    .MakeGenericMethod(innerListType, innerEnumerableType);

//expressions (parameters)
var innerParamx = Expression.Parameter(innerListType);
var outerParamx = Expression.Parameter(outerListType);

// listOfLists.Select(x => x.Cast<T>()); 
// as an expression
var castx = Expression.Call(castm, innerParamx);
var lambdax = Expression.Lambda(castx, innerParamx);
var selectx = Expression.Call(selectm, outerParamx, lambdax);
var lambdax2 = Expression.Lambda(selectx, outerParamx);

var result = lambdax2.Compile().DynamicInvoke(listOfLists);
```

you could optionally cached `lambdax2.Compile()` somewhere for each runtime type, performance.

Comment: interesting... call `Cast<>` with generics, hadn't thought of that. Yeah, that should work

Comment: ok you can do this much more simply, updated my ass answer based on yours :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is "you can't" - though I could probably be proven wrong with some super hacky code that uses a ton of reflection or emits IL directly or something.

The compiler and JIT'er needs to know the object types for everything to setup the stack, allocate memory properly, etc.

Perhaps every type T can implement some marker interface, or derive from a common base?  Various behaviors can be implemented virtually.  If you can comment a bit on what your program is trying to do, perhaps people could come up with a good design.

Comment: my inner type is coming from strings, specified at runtime (like ints, datetimes) and im parsing them. Its going into enumerables because i have many. +1 for reading the question, even if youre wrong.

Comment: So you have a bunch of strings of the same type, such as "1", "8", 10" or "10/6/2011", "10/10/2011", "10/15/2011" and you want to parse them and build IEnumerable<Int32> or IEnumerable<DateTime> or something?  I think you'd want to build your own collection type that can deserialize an array of strings, detect and store the type, and represent the data internally as enumerable objects of your own base type.  Either way, there's going to have to be a big switch statement of all the supported types somewhere.

Comment: yeah, I was trying at avoid abstracting over enumerables, looks like thats my only option though. thanks

Comment: Yea it's that or the weird reflection stuff others are suggesting (warning, it'll be a lot slower)..  I guess this is why people like their dynamic languages these days :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment,

> not exactly but thanks, i could create the inner list of the right
>   type, but then i can push objects into it and i still have the
>   variance issue

what I gather is that you get a variance issue on the objects that you are adding to the outer list although you are able to cast the inner list.

Based on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228359%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), what I understand is that you can use a workaround to instantiate the outer list,

```
// Simple workaround for single method
// Variance in one direction only
public static void Add<S, D>(List<S> source, List<D> destination)
    where S : D
{
    foreach (S sourceElement in source)
    {
        destination.Add(sourceElement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> void Test<T>()
{
  // Create a top IEnumeranble instance you should specify list element type
  var result = new List<IEnumerable<T>>();

  // Add an internal IEnumerable<T>
  result.Add(new List<T>());

  return result;
}
```

but if you already has an initialized `List<List<T>>` you just need a cast:

```
list.Cast<IEnumerable<T>>();
```

Comment: "when I only know T at runtime"

Comment: Yes you know T in run time but why you can't initialize your List of List in runtime?

Comment: for starters a `List<List<T>>` isnt `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`. Your code above talks of `T` at compile time.

Comment: T is generic type argument isn't it?