# Can you find objects of a type which takes in 2 generic types, but regardless of those types?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

Odd title, i know.

Basically, if you have a class e.g.:

```
public class SomeClass<T1, T2> : MonoBehaviour {}
```

is there any way to do something like this, `FindObjectsOfType<SomeClass<>>()`, and retrieve all existing `SomeClass` regardless of T1 and T2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly.

You can however use a little trick: Create a non-generic base class for it

```
public abstract class SomeBase : MonoBehaviour { }

public class SomeClass<T1, T2> : SomeBase { }
```

Now you can simply use

```
SomeBase[] instances = FindObjectsOfType<SomeBase>();
```

---

However this returns only the `SomeBase` type and you wouldn't get access to inner stuff of `SomeClass`. It is enough to access e.g. `transform` or `gameObject`.

You could add some `abstract` properties in order to be able to convert them to the correct type later:

```
public abstract class SomeBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract Type GetT1 { get; }
    public abstract Type GetT2 { get; }
}

public class SomeClass<T1, T2> : SomeBase
{
    public override Type GetT1
    {
        get { return typeof(T1); }
    }

    public override Type GetT2
    {
        get { return typeof(T2); }
    }
}
```

Now you can simply do e.g.

```
var test = FindObjectsOfType<SomeBase>();
foreach (var someClass in test)
{
    Debug.LogFormat("Instance found on {0}: T1={1}, T2={2}", someClass.name, someClass.GetT1.Name, someClass.GetT2.Name);
}
```

---

To further typecast the items to the target `SomeClass` I think you would need to use reflection. There are some examples like e.g. [How to cast a generic type at runtime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676989/how-to-cast-a-generic-type-at-runtime-in-c-sharp) or also [Cast generic type without knowing T?](https://forums.asp.net/t/1904461.aspx?Cast+generic+type+without+knowing+T+)