# Specifying the template class at run time with C# Generics

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-3.0

We have a class that for containing filter criteria used in searches. In the class is a dictionary of filter criteria which contains a value.

What I want to do is something like this.

```
protected string GetSearchValue(string name)
{
    if (!FilterCache.HasFilter(name)) return string.Empty;

    var filterType = FilterCache.GetFilterType(name);

    var filter = FilterCache.GetFilter<filterType>(name); // <- This fails

    if (filter == null || !filter.IsSet) return string.Empty;

    return filter.Value.ToString();         
}
```

GetFilterType looks like this:

```
    public Type GetFilterType(string name)
    {
        return SearchElements[name].GetType();
    }
```

In the end, I want to get the value of filter and return it to the UI.

Comment: Could you show us the definition of `SearchElements` and explain more what you want the type of `filter` to be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513952/c-sharp-specifying-generic-collection-type-param-at-runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use reflection to call a generic with the type parameter not known at compile time, like this:

```
var getFilterGeneric = typeof(FilterCache)
    .GetMethod("GetFilter")
    .MakeGenericMethod(filterType)
    .Invoke(typeof(FilterCache) /* or null */, name);
```