# How to parse a JToken or JObject's Value To A Dynamically Determined Type

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm hoping that someone could explain how/why this does not work for determining a object's type dynamically then using the type in generics.

This will work because I'm specifying DateTime explicitly hardcoded as the type:

```
string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exampleObject);
Type dataType = exampleObject.GetType();
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(serializedObject);
jObject.Value<DateTime>("propertyName");
```

However neither of these seem to work:

```
jObject.Value<typeof(dateType)>("propertyName");
jObject.Value<dateType>("propertyName");
```

How can I specify the type of an property correctly here:

```
jObject.Value<{WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE}>("propertyName");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are determining the `dataType` at runtime, however, `Value<>` needs to know the type at compile time.  For one thing `Value<T>` might have constraints on what `T` must be, and it can't perform these checks at compile time on `dataType` if it doesn't know what `dataType` will be.

Here are some answers that address what you are trying to accomplish, although dealing with collections, applies to runtime determined generic parameters in general:
[Specifying generic collection type param at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513952/specifying-generic-collection-type-param-at-runtime)

Note that your "{WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE}" is what they are calling the generic parameter.